# change $ to % sign in bash scripts

Tags: bash, cmd, cross-platform

I want to make some simple scripts work in NT cmd.exe and in bash. Looks like I can do it if I will make bash understand %1 %2 %* etc as valid $1 $2 $*. May be,there is some easy way to do it?

Comment: This is a terrible broken approach. What are you actually trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally a very bad idea to run the same script on compilers targeting different coding languages, what you're doing is like running javascript code on flash actionscript, sure, the syntax is similar but they're not the same...

What you could however do is install bash in windows :
http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/

Or installing wine in linux (generally a worse idea)...

The best practice is probably coding it in something that is designed to work cross platform like python